# WinPhone7 OData app crashing on WinPhone8 with System.Data.Services.Client

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, odata, windows-phone-8

I've got a Windows Phone 7 application that crashes on Windows Phone 8 devices. This is happening with identical XAPs (asserted both by downloading app in the market and deploying from local machine). Initial investigation shows that System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection is throwing NotSupportedExceptions on common operations (Select, for example) on WP8, but not on WP7.

The application is targeting the Windows Phone 7.1 OS target.

So far as I know, a WP7 app can't opt out of the WP8 marketplace, meaning compatibility issues like this can't easily be mitigated while we work on a WP8 version of the application.

Has anyone seen this behavior with the OData provider on Windows Phone? If so, any resolutions, workarounds or obvious solutions I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install [OData Client Tools for Windows Phone Apps](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35461)? If not, can you try after installing the client?